# How to insert a new line after each element in a list? Python

Tags: python

I tried to append some elements to a new list, and I wanted to separate each one by a new line. I tried this:

```
for i in list_rents:
        result.append("{}: {}\n".format(i, 'Caro' if i > avg else 'Precio razonable'))
    print("El precio promedio de la lista dada es {}, por lo que estas son las comparaciones independientes:\n    {}".format(avg, result))
```

The last part worked as I expected, but the first one did not, why does that happen, and how can I solve it?

Here's the output:

```
El precio promedio de la lista dada es 24.166666666666668, por lo que estas son las comparaciones independientes:
    ['21.0: Precio razonable\n', '12.0: Precio razonable\n', '32.0: Caro\n', '23.0: Precio razonable\n', '43.0: Caro\n', '14.0: Precio razonable\n']
```

And here is the full code:

```
result = []
ans = input('Quieres agregar un elemento a la lista de precios de rentas? (S) Si,  (N) No.')
while ans == 'S':
    new_value = float(input('Ingrese el valor del nuevo elemento'))
    if new_value > 0: 
        list_rents.append(new_value)
    else:            
        print('Programa terminado, ese es un valor inaceptable')
        sys.exit()
    ans = input('Quieres agregar un elemento a la lista de precios de rentas? (S) Si,  (N) No.')
avg = sum(list_rents)/len(list_rents)
for i in list_rents:
    result.append("{}: {}\n".format(i, 'Caro' if i > avg else 'Precio razonable'))
print("El precio promedio de la lista dada es {}, por lo que estas son las comparaciones independientes:\n    {}".format(avg, result))
```

Comment: what do you mean by `last part worked as I expected, but the first one did not`? It has created a list for you. Are you trying to get a single string that has new line included in it? For example: `'21.0: Precio razonable\n12.0: Precio razonable\n32.0: Caro\n23.0: Precio razonable\n43.0: Caro\n14.0: Precio razonable\n'` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to turn a list of strings `li` into a single string, joined by newlines, you should use `"\n".join(li)`, instead of adding a newline to each string individually (because you'll still have a list then).

Comment: Worked! Thanks dude!